# How to determine if image is asset or network image

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a profile edit screen where I edit the profile image. If the image is uploaded then it is obviously network image and it will not be displayed in AssetImage widget

```
        CircleAvatar(
          radius: 60,
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage('some/path'),
        ),
```

However if I edit the image then it will be AssetImage because it will come from device photo album or camera

```
        CircleAvatar(
          radius: 60,
          backgroundImage: AssetImage('some/path'),
        ),
```

So how can we display both images in one widget? Or in other words how to determine if the image is network or asset image so we can pick the right ImageProvider?

Comment: *"[...] so we can pick the right ImageProvider?"* what you mean by that?

Comment: @pskink `NetworkImage` and `AssetImage` are ImageProvider types

Comment: yes, i know - whats the problem with them? what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: @pskink well I want to display in that `CircleAvatar` both types of images - network and assets. To do that I need to specify `ImageProvider` in `backgroundImage` property of `CircleAvatar` widget.. To do that I need to know if the path to the image is network or assets. Hope that make sense.. I'm struggle with it all day and it makes me all confused already

Comment: @pskink I think I solved it.. Instead of using `AssetImage` or `NetworkImage` I can use `FileImage`.  Transferring images from camera or device album into a File is easy process and transfer network image into a file can be done with this handy package https://pub.dev/packages/network_to_file_image I haven't  tested it on 100% yet but it looks promising